# how to crop image and save the position in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop

I want to crop an image in matlab, so i build a gui. When i click the button eg <kbd>select region</kbd> the user can enter points in `imagA`. After that click button called <kbd>crop</kbd> and the image has been cropped. How to crop another image called `imagB`, have same position with `imagA`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`imcrop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html) to crop an image *and* get the cropping rect back.
Suppose you have two images (`imagA` and `imagB`) you want to crop in the same manner:

```
figure;
imshow( imagA );title('please crop');
[cA rect] = imcrop; %// interactive cropping of imagA
cB = imcrop( imagB, rect ); %// non-interactive way to crop imagB using same crop rect as imagA
```